# How to add a user to Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: 12.04, adduser

This is very weird, when add a user using the command line then set a password I cant login using the GUI!
is this a new thing or what?

Comment: Depends on the command used... 1 thing that is important: did you specify a /home?

Comment: No I didn't, I just used useradd with no options

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can add an new user (with the common options, and `/home/[user]` as home directory) with:

```
useradd -m -g users -s /bin/bash [user]
```

and then to set a password:

```
passwd [user]
```

EDIT: You can also add additional information about the user with:

```
chfn [user]
```

Comment: does this mean that useradd <new user> does not work unless I use the -m -g switches?

Comment: `-m` creates you home folder in `/home/[user]`, and `-g` adds you to the groups `users`, which I am not sure if is set by default. If you just used `useradd [user]`, then probably you would run into problems, as the GUI requires both.

Answer (score 0):

Please check your CapsLock and Language options (must be EN), also check if you have space in the password.

The command for creating new user is:

`sudo adduser USERNAME` (do not use spaces in the username)

After that you will specify the name of the user. Leave other options blank by push Enter.

Comment: This is exactly what I did, it didn't work

Comment: Then try to change the password. Use comand: sudo passwd username